# Avoid URL Encoding at Browsers

Tags: c#, url, encode, urlencode

Im working with a c# project. 
I have got a string that contains physical path. And creating and url with this string than open web browser. When i open browser its changing some characters. How can i avoid changing my string?

```
  string oldurl = @"C:\Records\12\[%3AOperator(Santral)] _05324516171-12_20191004115323(135).wav";
  Process.Start("http://10.41.1.33:8182/RECORDINGURL=" + url);
```

When i opened this url its changing like this at browser 
**new url string** = **"C:/Records/12/[%3AOperator(Santral)]%20_05324516171-12_20191004115323(135).wav"**

Is there a way to avoid changing any character?

Comment: your browser does this, not dotnet

Comment: I know this. im asking how can i avoid  what i have to do ?

Comment: basically, avoid using unsafe characters such as `space, < ,>, #, %, {, }, |, \, ^, ~, [, ]` as the browsers will automatically encode unsafe characters.